# Use relative paths for extra-lib-dirs on cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a C library "myboo" which has Makefile. I want to make a wrapper of this library.
I don't want to install it into /usr/local since "myboo" is not a major module.
Additionally it is recommended that I build "myboo" not as a dynamic library
but as a static library.

I make custom Setup.py to build "myboo";

```
main :: IO ()
main = defaultMainWithHooks simpleUserHooks {
           preBuild = \a b -> makeLib a b >> preBuild simpleUserHooks a b
           }

makeLib :: Args -> BuildFlags -> IO ()
makeLib _ flags = do
  let verbosity = fromFlag $ buildVerbosity flags
  cflags <- lookupEnv "CFLAGS" >>= return . maybe "" id
  setEnv "CFLAGS" $ "-fPIC" ++ (' ' : cflags)
  rawSystemExit verbosity "env" ["make", "--directory=myboo", "libmyboo.a"]
```

And I arrange myboo.cabal to link my haskell codes to C library;

```
library
  exposed-modules:     MyBoo
  build-depends:       base >=4.7 && <4.8
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  include-dirs: myboo
  extra-libraries: myboo
  extra-lib-dirs: myboo
```

When I run "cabal build", I got following messages.

```
myboo-0.1.0.0: library-dirs: myboo is a relative path which makes no sense (as
there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make paths relative to the
package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use --force to override)
```

If I write "extra-lib-dirs: /absolute/path/to/working/dir/myboo", it seems that it works well.
But it's not good way because /absolute/... is just a working directory.

How should I fix above error messages? My environment is here;

```
% ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.2
% cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.20.0.2
using version 1.20.0.0 of the Cabal library
% cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write your own Setup.hs and setup `Distribution.Simple.confHook`. In your hook function, modify `Distribution.PackageDescription.extraLibDirs` to include the directory.

Note that you also need to change the `build-type` to `Custom` in your cabal file.

Here is a link to [Setup.hs](https://github.com/snakamura/volare/blob/master/Setup.hs) in which I did what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but...

Now you can use relative path to set `extra-include-dirs` and `extra-lib-dirs` options in `stack.yaml`. For example, for some package `A`, it would look like this:

```
extra-include-dirs:
- ../my-c-lib/src

extra-lib-dirs:
- ../my-c-lib/build
```

assuming both `A` and `my-c-lib` are stored in the same folder.

That's it. It doesn't require you to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable (until you run executable). But, if you have a package `B` which uses `A`, you have to add `A`'s `extra-..-dirs` to `B`'s `stack.yaml`. Otherwise you'll get `Missing C library` error. Also, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` must be set here in order to prevent `can't load .so/.DLL` error during `B`'s building.

Basically it's a workaround for building local packages. I wouldn't use it for public package because it forces a user to either modify `stack.yaml` or to store dependend packages in the same folder.

Comment: How did you get this to work with relative paths? Manual says Paths should be absolute https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#extra-include-dirsextra-lib-dirs

Comment: @Flip well I didn't do anything except that. Usually, when I have to deal with ffi, I just make a two projects. They both sit in some directory called **root-dir**. So, for example, let haskell part be `root-dir/some-hs` and C part be `root-dir/some-c`. I set `extra-include-dirs` and `extra-lib-dirs` just as I shown in the answer. And it just works (assuming that there are `src` and `build` folders in C part). I'm glad it works because otherwise it would be too painful to deal with. I even did such a project recently and it still works. Let me know if it doesn't work for you. I'll try to help.

Comment: @Flip Also, I don't think you have to have a hierarchy like mine. I believe you can use `../../` or `../../../` but I didn't try it. So I can't tell for sure. Anyway, it would be quite strange if `../` is allowed but `../../` is not. I hope such trick won't be "fixed" in never versions of stack :D