# Link statically to local `.a` file

Tags: build, linker, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack

I would like to create a library that links statically to a local `.a` file.

To make it more concrete, here's an HPack `package.yaml` that creates a binary `phase2` that statically links to `cobj/libImpl.a`:

```
name: clashilator-model-phase2
version: 0
category: acme

dependencies:
  - base

executables:
  phase2:
    main: phase2.hs        
    source-dirs: src
    include-dirs: csrc
    build-tools: hsc2hs

    extra-libraries: stdc++ 
    extra-lib-dirs: cobj
    ghc-options:
      -O3 -fPIC -pgml g++
      -optl-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition
      -optl-Wl,--whole-archive -optl-Wl,-Bstatic
      -optl-Wl,-L./cobj -optl-Wl,-lImpl
      -optl-Wl,-Bdynamic -optl-Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Now, if I try to do the same with a library, two things go wrong:

```
name: clashilator-model-phase2
version: 0
category: acme

dependencies:
  - base

library:
  source-dirs: src
  include-dirs: csrc
  build-tools: hsc2hs

  exposed-modules:
    - Interface

  extra-libraries: stdc++
  extra-lib-dirs: cobj
  ghc-options:
    -O3 -fPIC -pgml g++
    -optl-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition
    -optl-Wl,--whole-archive -optl-Wl,-Bstatic
    -optl-Wl,-L./cobj -optl-Wl,-lImpl
    -optl-Wl,-Bdynamic -optl-Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

1. The `extra-lib-dirs` flag freaks Cabal out:

> `clashilator-model-phase2-0`: `library-dirs`: `cobj` is a relative path which makes
>   no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make paths
>   relative to the package database itself by using $`{pkgroot}`. (use `--force` to
>   override)

[Supposedly, this can be worked around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24448226/477476) by writing a custom `Setup.hs`.

2. If I follow the above answer, or I remove the `extra-lib-dirs` flag, the build seemingly succeeds, but alas, the resulting `.a` file doesn't link to `libImpl.a`:

```
$ nm .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/libHSclashilator-model-phase2-0-Da0NUHx0OMlCviQdOLebNo.a |grep bar
                 U bar
```

Consequently, trying to use the resulting library from another Cabal/Stack project in an executable fails at linking.